# Select multiple columns and remove values according to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe which looks like this:

```
StudentID  Name       Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3
0    s1    user1           7           7           -3
1    s2    user2           2          15           10
2    s3    user3          12          10           10
3    s4    user4           6           2           10
4    s5    user5          -2           7            2
```

And I would like to select the `Assignment`values limited to the values of this list:

```
[-3,0,2,4,7,10,12]
```

So the output I would like to get are:

```
Error_values:
StudentID  Name       Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3
1    s2    user2           2          15           10
3    s4    user4           6           2           10
4    s5    user5          -2           7            2

Correct_values:
StudentID  Name       Assignment1 Assignment2 Assignment3
0    s1    user1           7           7           -3
2    s3    user3          12          10           10
```

I can so far get the `correct_values`by

```
def loadData(filename):
    raw_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    return raw_data

def checkErrorsData(raw_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(raw_data), columns=raw_data.columns)
    duplicated_Id = df[df.duplicated('StudentID', keep=False)]
    error_data = df[df['Assignment1'].isin([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])]
    return duplicated_Id, error_data
```

However, this needs to address every column, how can I do this for all columns without typing their label?

Comment: Can we see ur code, to see if you are in the right track

Comment: Yes, Just edit it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` create a sub dataframe with all of the assignment values.  You then use `isin` together with `all` to identify which contain all of the target test values (specifying axis=1 for rows).

```
target_test_values = [-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12]
>>> df[df.loc[:, ['Assignment1', 'Assignment2', 'Assignment3']]
       .isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)]

  StudentID   Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
0        s1  user1            7            7           -3
2        s3  user3           12           10           10
```

Or, assuming you have three assignments:

```
assignments = 3
>>> df[df.iloc[:, 2:(2+1+assignments)].isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)]
  StudentID   Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
0        s1  user1            7            7           -3
2        s3  user3           12           10           10
```

If there will be no further columns past assignments, you can simply index as follows:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 2:].isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)]
```

And to get the error values, you just need to use the tilda (~) negation:

```
>>> df[~df.iloc[:, 2:].isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)]
  StudentID   Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
1        s2  user2            2           15           10
3        s4  user4            6            2           10
4        s5  user5           -2            7            2
```

It is more efficient to assign the boolean indexing to a mask as follows:

```
mask = df.iloc[:, 2:].isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)
correct_values = df[mask]
error_values = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thanks!, but what happens if I have `n assignments`, and I can't type all the column labels?

Comment: I almost used index assignment but opted for labels for clarity.  You can use `df[df.iloc[:, 2:(2+1+n)].isin(target_test_values).all(axis=1)]` where `n` is the number of assignments. See edit.

Comment: Hey Thank you. It works properly, and thanks for taking it further, I was assuming the tilda negation for getting error values as well.

Comment: I'll include a slightly more efficient version as well.